# Simple python question: accessing class data member

Tags: python, class

I have a class which defines data attributes.

```
class channel:
    def __init(self,var1, var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var1
        #etc
```

So far so simple. But what I'd like to do is to have a method that specifies which data attribute to use so that I can generically use it to do the same thing with different data attriutes depending on the arguments, something like (obviously this is not right)

```
def fun(list_of_channels, var1):
    for chan in list_of_channels:
        #use chan.var1
```

but be able to use var2 as an argument to access chan.var2 if I called

```
fun(list_of_channels,var2)
```

Is there an obvious way to do this that I've missed?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [getattr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) like this:

```
def fun(list_of_channels, attr_name):
    for chan in list_of_channels:
        attr = getattr(chan, attr_name)
        ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Is the [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) function what you need?